# Laravel - How to select only the expired data in a DB query?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have a query in which I want to see only the Model's name and the expired dates of it

My query looks like this:

```
 $cars = DB::table('taga_cars')
        ->whereDate('seriesasiudata2','<',\Carbon\Carbon::now())
        ->orWhereDate('cmrinsurancedata2','<',\Carbon\Carbon::now())
        ->orWhereDate('rcadata2','<',\Carbon\Carbon::now())
        ->orWhereDate('cascodata2','<',\Carbon\Carbon::now())
        ->orWhereDate('copieconformadata2','<',\Carbon\Carbon::now())
        ->orWhereDate('cemtdata2','<',\Carbon\Carbon::now())
        ->select('name','seriesasiudata2','cmrinsurancedata2','rcadata2','copieconformadata2','cemtdata2')
       ->get();
```

The problem is this query displays all input dates and I would want only the expired ones to be visible, for example if seriesasiudata2 is the only expired one, I want only it to be displayed

Comment: Can't you just `select` only that column?

Comment: Well, I do not know which column would expire this was just an example

Comment: can you show us ur migration code ?